# Create local user with PowerShell (Windows Vista)

Tags: powershell, adsi

I've installed PowerShell recently and one of the first things I started looking for was how to create a new user. After looking for some time I still haven't found this.
I have a little experience in bash on linux and find it very effective. Creating users there is trivial.
Is there an easy\built-in way to create a local user with PowerShell?

Thank you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the localhost's [ADSI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa772170.aspx):

```
function create-account ([string]$accountName = "testuser") {   
   $hostname = hostname   
   $comp = [adsi] "WinNT://$hostname"  
   $user = $comp.Create("User", $accountName)   
   $user.SetPassword("Password1")   
   $user.SetInfo()   
}
```

Comment: If you're scripting creating a user with a password, you probably also want that user's password to not expire: `$user.Put('userFlags', [int]$user.userFlags.Value -bor 0x00010000) # ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD`

Answer (score 7):

you can also use

```
net user /add
```

this command isn't limited to powershell.