# New-LocalUser not recognized on Win 7

Tags: powershell, windows-7

I'm in the process of writing a script that will create a new local user on a machine. It works as intended on the Win 10 machine I've been testing it on, but when I tested it on a Win 7 machine I received an error message saying "The term 'New-LocalUser' is now recognized as the name of a cmdlet...'Is there a different way to create a new local user on Win 7?

Here is the script to create the user:

```
$Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "p@ssw0rd" -AsPlainText -Force
New-LocalUser -Name "Presentation" -Password $Password -PasswordNeverExpires:$true -UserMayNotChangePassword:$true
```

Comment: What version of powershell are you using on the Win7 box? New-LocalUser was added in 5.1 I think.

Comment: take a look at the following - it uses ADSI ... adsi - Create local user with PowerShell (Windows Vista) - Stack Overflow — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383390/create-local-user-with-powershell-windows-vista

Comment: Looks like it's running 2.0. Guess we update it.

Answer (score 3):

You have to install the  Windows Management Framework 5.1 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54616). The command was added there.

Comment: Interesting. Was there a way to create localusers via powershell before that was released?

Comment: what @Lee_Dailey says.

Comment: hmm I installed this on a Windows Server 2012 R2 machine and this didn't install this command?